# Java file doesn't save new lines in the end of all lines

Tags: java, save

I've a problem with saving data to csv file.
When I want save data, it saves it sth like this:

```
new data
2017-02-12
new
```

But I'd like it save sth like this in the end of the file:

```
new data,2017-02-12,new
```

My code:

```
public static void writeData(String filepath, List<String> lines) {

    Path file = Paths.get(filepath);
    try {
        Files.write(file, lines, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong with saving data to file!");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

`Files.write(Path, Iterable<? extends CharSequence>, OpenOption...)` is writing to file line by line. If your list contains items "new data", "2017-02-12", "new" then each item will be printed on separate line.

If you want to print them together at single line you have to concatenate them before adding to your list.

```
String[] columns = new String[] {"new data", "2017-02-12", "new"};
String row = String.join(",", columns);
List<String> rows = new LinkedList<>();
rows.add(row);

// calling your method to save lines
writeData("data.csv", rows);
```

Comment: Could you edit my function and add your code in the right place, please ?

Comment: Hi, all the code is done before calling your method, you just need to ensure, that your list contains row made of concatenated columns instead of columns itself.

Comment: I think it can't run : String columns = new String[] {"new data", "2017-02-12", "new"};

Comment: sorry, i forget to add `[]` on the declaration side, the correct form is `String[] columns = new String[]{"new data", "2017-02-12", "new"};`

Comment: I did it, but in a really simple way -> 
String row = "new data"+","+ "2017-02-12"+","+ "new";

        List<String> rows = new ArrayList<String>();
        rows.add(row);

Comment: @matoni You can shorten your code for joining by using `String row = String.join(",", columns);`

Comment: @Thomas Fritsch thanks for suggestion. I was searching for such a method in `StringJoiner` but without success :), good to know it is contained in `String` class.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the wrong function to write the data to your file. To quote the Java API for the function Files::write you are using:

"Each line is a char sequence and is written to the file in sequence with each line terminated by the platform's line separator, as defined by the system property line.separator. "
([source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)))

The "line separator" is something like "\n", "\n\r", "\r" (depending on your file system).